# Assert issue in selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to assert the other language text .While asserting i am getting a error message

```
Expected: a string containing "Fornavn er et felt som mÃƒÂ¥ fylles ut." but: was "Fornavn er et felt som må fylles ut."
```

Below is the Code i am using in the framework

```
default void assertElementContainsText(WebElementFacade element, String text) {
        try {
            Assert.assertThat(element.waitUntilVisible().waitUntilClickable().getText(), CoreMatchers.containsString(text));
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Could not find element " + element);
        }
    }
```

Its working fine for the English language when its comparing with other language getting the issue as

```
Expected: a string containing "Fornavn er et felt som mÃƒÂ¥ fylles ut."
     but: was "Fornavn er et felt som må fylles ut."
```

Comment: I am not sure about this language but the texts are different. First text: `mÃƒÂ¥` and second text: `må`

Comment: in application i am getting "Fornavn er et felt som må fylles ut." but when i get the text its getting saved as "Fornavn er et felt som mÃƒÂ¥ fylles ut." so getting failed in assertion

Comment: Assert.assertThat(element.waitUntilVisible().waitUntilClickable().getText(), CoreMatchers.containsString(text));

Comment: The Java file was not saved as UTF-8, so the expected string is being corrupted when the file is saved. Check for an option in your editor for setting which character set to use when creating a file.

Comment: Are you using eclipse ide?

Comment: no i am using inteliji

Comment: I am just getting the text and Asserting with the stored text in json

Comment: Can you change encoder format.  Project Encoding -> UTF-8 Like this https://jetbrains.com/help/idea/encoding.html#file-encoding-settings